# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns false after redirect and validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a problem with MVC4 user authorization.

`System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser` returns `true.`

Then it gets to `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` and I see a cookie in my browser.

Then `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` still evaluates to `false` for some reason.

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

is still `false` after a redirect and stays `false.`

```
model.UserName
```

is not `null or empty` when I call `SetAuthCookie`. It has the correct username.

forms authentication is specified in `web.config.`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See also **System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal**
You should see

- AuthenticationType   "Forms"
- IsAuthenticated      true
- Name             "fred"

Did you tell MVC/IIS to authorize your controller ?
eg

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : Controller
```

If  **User.Identity**  is not set, it would suggest WEB.CONFIG or an explicit AUTHORIZE attribute is missing.